# How to create a below date popup

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker, popup

When user hovers/clicks on "month" button, I should get the pop up which contains the months as shown here.

[image]

Kindly guide me to start with this application. How should I start with this kind of date pop up in angularJS.

Any light thrown on this topic will really be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview). Specifically the section about "Setting the calander start view".

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to some extent